# MySql Triggers and update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with a date field in it tableA when a record is updated I would like a trigger to check the date field and if it is greater than a certain date set another field active to 'yes'

I've tried but can't seem to get it right

Comment: You use the "edit" button to add your current code to the question, together with an explanation of how it fails to work.

Comment: You need to provide more context here, especially in the form of some SQL.

Comment: It will be much better if you can also provide your code.

Comment: It was difficult to do this as I was using navicat, once I had created the trigger I couldn't see the SQL which had created it. Also the error messages were not very helpful after a lot of reading on mysql.com I solved it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Managed to work it out as follows,

TRIGGER `active` BEFORE INSERT ON `tableA`
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
IF(NEW.install_date > '1999-01-01') THEN
SET NEW.active='yes';
ELSE
SET NEW.active = OLD.active;
END IF;
END
```